Determine used size in custom memory area on ARM microcontroller
I am implementing an application on an ARM 32 bits microcontroller where I use part of the internal flash to store some persistant values.
For that I added the following to the linker script:
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 20K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 63K
  STORAGE_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN =  ORIGIN(FLASH) + LENGTH(FLASH), LENGTH = 1K
}
SECTIONS
{
  ._customStorage :
  {
    _sCustomStorage = .;
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(._customStorage))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eCustomStorage = .;
  } >STORAGE_FLASH
}

In the main program I will be callig a function to write on the flash memory in which I would pass addresses as parameters.
I want to know if it would be possible to somehow count how many times the function was called with different addresses (if they are a constant, at least) to make an estimate about how much memory is being consumed.
Since different calls might be writing different sizes it would be better to multiply the address parameter with the size parameter, but that seems more difficult. Since for my application most write operations are 16bits this functionality would not be super necessary.
What I am doing now is mentally estimating the memory and doing the following:
#define OCCUPIED_SIZE 50
const uint8_t __attribute__((section ("._customStorage"))) ___occupiedMemory[OCCUPIED_SIZE];

For example, with the following code:
bool writeFlash(uint32_t address,uint8_t* data,uint16_t size);
int main(){
   uint8_t value = 0;
   uint8_t array[50] = {};
   bool flag; //Not initialized indicating value is not determined by compiler
   writeFlash(12,&value,1);
   writeFlash(34,&array,7);
   writeFlash(34,&array,10);
   if(flag){
       writeFlash(67,&array,10);
   }
}

I'd like linker to report 24 bytes are used (extra 3 from "ALIGN").

Why is it important "to somehow count how many times the function was called" or don't I understand your wording? (English is not my native language.) Why can't you simply run your application and have the flashing function track the range? It should suffice to track the minimum and maximum addresses.

If all your variables that are in flash are located in that specific section, then you should know the size of used memory just by looking into the map file. Could your flash functions be called with addressed of other variables? Don't you have access to the calling functions?

Besided that: How would counting the number of calls provide the amount of memory? If you write very different sizes in each call, just counting calls won't be very useful.

@thebusybee while I can (And will) make sure no call can write outside of the availabe area, I want the liker to report how much of the memory is being occupied for 2 reasons: to konw how much headroom I have and to make the program to fail compilation

@Gerhardh I do know the size and location of the areas I can write to. The flash functions themselves can be called with whatever values, ofc I can return error when outside of bounds. Regarding the second question, it's true that counting calls can be missleading since they might have different sizes (in my case most of them will be 16bits), it would be better to multiply ammout of calls with the parameter which sets the size, but I didn't thought that would be possible. Will add this to the question

Huh, "multiply the address parameter with the size parameter"? That does not sense at all.

Your source code should provide all necessary information, like addresses and sizes. Just collect the calls of the flashing function and evaluate them. Since this is simple and straightforward, I must assume you thought about it. Why does this not work for you?

The linker will generate an error if you overflow the specified size, for sure. You don't need to know the headroom. As Gerhardh says, the map file is your first stop to see details.

However, if you have addresses and/or sizes unknown during compile time, how would the linker know more? I still don't see your problem. Please clarify, for example by a [mre].

As I said on the post, I am not expecting to calculate the cases where addresses and/or sizes are undetermined at compile time. Only on the ones that have a value at compile time. Will add some sample code and expected result by the linker

Doing my best to answer, although the goal of the above code is not totally clear to me.

I'd like linker to report 24 bytes are used (extra 3 from "ALIGN").

It is impossible for the linker to report information determined at runtime. So the exact question you're asking is impossible. That rules out any solution that uses writeFlash() to write to this special memory region at runtime.


I want to know if it would be possible ... to make an estimate about how much memory is being consumed.

However, If you know what data is going to be written to ._customStorage at link-time instead, then you can write data to the ._customStorage section at link time and know exactly how much flash in ._customStorage is consumed.
For example, the following C code,
#define IN_CUSTOM_STORAGE __attribute__((section("._customStorage")))
const uint8_t IN_CUSTOM_STORAGE one_chunk_in_storage[50] = { 0 }; // init as desired ...
const uint8_t IN_CUSTOM_STORAGE another_stored_thing[16] = { 0 }; // init as desired ...
const uint16_t IN_CUSTOM_STORAGE one_16b_store = 0xABCD;

with the following in your linker script,
SECTIONS
{
  ._customStorage :
  {
    _sCustomStorage = .;
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(._customStorage))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eCustomStorage = .;
  } > STORAGE_FLASH
  used_custom_storage = _eCustomStorage - _sCustomStorage;
...
}

will cause the contents of one_chunk_in_storage, another_stored_thing and one_16b_store to be written to the STORAGE_FLASH region of memory when the image is flashed to your microcontroller.
If you want to know exactly how much space in STORAGE_FLASH is consumed at link time, then you can add -Wl,-Map=appimage.map to your linker flags the "appimage.map" file that's generated along with your binary will tell you what you want.
If you want to know exactly how much space is consumed from within the C program, then this function will tell you:
size_t how_much_data_in_storage()
{
    // This symbol was calculated in the linker script
    extern const char used_custom_storage[];
    return (size_t)used_custom_storage;
}


If your use case really does need to store data determined at run time, then you may want to look into a "key value store" or KVS for structuring writes into flash, because the details can get hairy.

Just to note, my linker script examples were in GNU LD syntax. It probably won't work for other linkers.

I know linker cannot report information determined at runtime, that is why I only mention calls with constant parameters. I was wondering if one could make linker(or compilwe tbh) detect function calls and do somethig with them (like define a symbol or smth) so I can create a dummy variable with the corresponding size

"if one could make linker(or compilwe tbh) detect function calls and do somethig with them" - fun thought, but I am fairly certain this is not something the linker or compiler can do on its own. I'd look for a different approach than using this function call to write to flash.

You mean not to use a function to write to flash? How could something like that be implemented? Like writing the same code(changing registers) on multiple places or you mean using a function with different caracteristics?
